# for huge arrays is numpy slower than list?

Tags: python, numpy

check my following code; it is part of sigma_2 function (using crude sieving) implemented in python which is one of divisor functions http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html

```
from time import time
from itertools import count
import numpy

def sig2(N, nump=False):
    init = time()


    #initialize array with value=1 since every positive integer is divisible by 1
    if nump:
        print 'using numpy'
        nums = numpy.ones((N,), dtype=numpy.int64)
    else:        
        nums = [1 for i in xrange(1, N)]

    #for each number n < N, add n*n to n's multiples
    for n in xrange(2, N):
        nn = n*n
        for i in count(1):
            if n*i >= N: break
            nums[n*i-1] += nn

    print 'sig2(n) done - {} ms'.format((time()-init)*1000)
```

I tried it with varying values and with numpy it is quite disappointing.

for 2000:

```
sig2(n) done - 4.85897064209 ms
took : 33.7610244751 ms
using numpy
sig2(n) done - 31.5930843353 ms
took : 55.6900501251 ms
```

for 200000:

```
sig2(n) done - 1113.80600929 ms
took : 1272.8869915 ms
using numpy
sig2(n) done - 4469.48194504 ms
took : 4705.97100258 ms
```

it goes on and my code isn't really scalable - for it not being O(n), but with these two and besides these two result using numpy causes performance problems. Shouldn't numpy be faster than python lists and dicts? That was my impression on numpy.

Comment: I don't see how your function implements divisor functions. Which is the return value?

Comment: It returns list of numbers whose sigma_2 matches given criteria. Only a fraction of the code is here ...

Answer (score 6):

As @unutbu said numpy really shines when you use vectorised operations. Here is an optimised implementation using numpy (it is consistent with the definition of divisor function from Mathworld):

```
import numpy as np

def sig2_numpy(N):

    x = np.arange(1,N+1)
    x[(N % x) != 0] = 0
    return np.sum(x**2)
```

When you call it, it is much faster:

```
>> import time
>> init = time.time()
>> print sig2_numpy(20000)
>> print "It took", (time.time()-init)*1000., 'ms'
It took 0.916957855225 ms
```

Comment: Please don't use the `<>` operator, it's been "considered obsolescent" at least since [Python 2.0](http://docs.python.org/release/2.0/ref/comparisons.html) (2000). I've replaced it with `!=`.

Comment: Oh btw., `np.sum(x**2) == np.dot(x,x)`. The latter might be faster because it doesn't produce the intermediate `x**2` array.

Comment: Yes, you are right `%timeit np.sum(x**2) -> 8.88 ms per loop` vs `%timeit np.dot(x,x) ->  1.78 ms per loop` (for 1e6 elements). I will leave the answer as it is, because it might be easier to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

NumPy achieves speed by performing calculations on whole arrays, rather than on single values at a time.

When you write

```
    for i in count(1):
        if n*i >= N: break
        nums[n*i-1] += nn
```

you are forcing the NumPy array `nums` to increment single values in an array one index at a time. That is a slow operation for NumPy arrays.

Comment: for that part, if I use numpy to generate another array whose value is 0 if index isn't divisible by n and n*n for n's multiples and perform array addition operation, will it speedup my code?

Comment: @thkang: correct answer: probably. Better answer: try it.

Comment: It seems @btel has implemented what you've described.